# When converting a string to time with strtotime() in PHP it adds one hour, why?

Tags: php, strtotime

When I am converting date using `strtotime()` function it automatically added 1 hour in existing date.

For example:

```
$PublishDate = "1/13/2012 **17**:0";
echo strtotime($PublishDate);

// OUTPUT : 1/13/2012 **18**:0
```

Why 1 hour is incremented automatically?

Comment: The above code shouldnt print out a date, but a unix time code. Can you give us the line you are using to print the date?

Comment: also, do you have a default timezone set in php?

Comment: `strtotime()` only support a limited number of date formats for input (http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php), and afaik this isn't one of them. Maybe you better use a combination of `strptime()` and `mktime()`, or use the static constructor of the `DateTime` class.

Answer (score 0):

Something odd is going on here. `strtotime()` converts attempts to convert a string representation of a date to the Unix time format (see [the strtotime() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)). Unix time is the total number of seconds since January 1st, 1970. This ends up being a large number, such as 1326723022 (the current Unix time as of writing). You can read more about Unix time [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

`strtotime()` should ALWAYS return either a 32 bit integer or FALSE (-1 in older versions of php).